Flutter: OptionsViewBuilder Not Fully Selectable Across Two Autocomplete TextFields
I have two Autocomplete Widgets, and I need their text fields to be positioned side by side. Additionally, I want the optionsViewBuilder for both to span the full width from the start of the first text field to the end of the second. To achieve this, I used CompositedTransformTarget and CompositedTransformFollower, and it works perfectly as intended.
However, the logic isn't working perfectly. I'm facing an issue with the second TextField: only the area directly below this TextField is selectable and scrollable, while the area directly below the first TextField is not selectable or scrollable for the second optionsViewBuilder.
only the area in the black box is selectable or scrollable for the second Autocomplete Widget as showen in this foto 
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final LayerLink layerLink = LayerLink();
    final List<String> fruits = [
      'Apple',
      'Banana',
      'Cherry',
      'Grapes',
    ];
    final List<String> vegetables = [
      'Carrot',
      'Broccoli',
      'Spinach',
      'Potato',
    ];
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 200,
        ),
        CompositedTransformTarget(
          link: layerLink,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Autocomplete(
                  optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) => fruits,
                  optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) =>
                      CompositedTransformFollower(
                    targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    link: layerLink,
                    child: MyAutocompleteOptionsViewBuilder<String>(
                      options: options,
                      onSelected: onSelected,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Autocomplete(
                  optionsBuilder: (textEditingValue) => vegetables,
                  optionsViewBuilder: (context, onSelected, options) =>
                      CompositedTransformFollower(
                    targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    link: layerLink,
                    child: MyAutocompleteOptionsViewBuilder<String>(
                      options: options,
                      onSelected: onSelected,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyAutocompleteOptionsViewBuilder<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAutocompleteOptionsViewBuilder({
    super.key,
    required this.options,
    required this.onSelected,
  });
  final Iterable<T> options;
  final void Function(T) onSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Material(
        elevation: 4.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemCount: options.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final option = options.elementAt(index);
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(option.toString()),
                onTap: () {
                  onSelected(option);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


github problem link
